# SSL Certificate Location on UNIX/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, ssl, ssl-certificate, filesystems

Is there any standard or convention for where SSL certificates and associated private keys should go on the UNIX/Linux filesystem?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

For system-wide use, OpenSSL should provide you `/etc/ssl/certs` and `/etc/ssl/private`. The latter of which will be restricted `700` to `root:root`.

If you have an application that doesn’t perform initial [privilege separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation) from `root`, then it might suit you to locate them somewhere local to the application with the relevantly restricted ownership and permissions.

Comment: is this standardized somewhere? The file system hierarchy standard doesn't contain it.

Comment: @cweiske This seems to be historical OpenSSL convention, not formally standardized, and a very unwieldy one in my opinion. My earliest trace is this version: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/38501/dir/redhat_other/com/openssl-0.9.3a-3.i386.rpm.html

Comment: Worth noting that this is only Debian based distros.

Comment: Could I store the SSL certificates (e.g. Let's Encrypt or Cloudflare) for the websites here too? Thanks!

Comment: Arch and CentOS also stores ca certs in `/etc/ssl/certs` as far as I can see

Comment: I had to read the first sentence a few times before I understood it. `For system wide use OpenSSL` a comma is missing after "use", but it's not possible to edit it.

Comment: This is not correct. /etc/ssl/certs is for root certs. Don’t store your server certs there.

Comment: and where is this on docker bullseye based image variants?

Answer (score 120):

[This is where Go looks for public root certificates](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_linux.go):

```
"/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",                // Debian/Ubuntu/Gentoo etc.
"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt",                  // Fedora/RHEL 6
"/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem",                            // OpenSUSE
"/etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem",                           // OpenELEC
"/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem", // CentOS/RHEL 7
"/etc/ssl/cert.pem",                                 // Alpine Linux
```

[Also](http://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/root_unix.go):

```
"/etc/ssl/certs",               // SLES10/SLES11, https://golang.org/issue/12139
"/system/etc/security/cacerts", // Android
"/usr/local/share/certs",       // FreeBSD
"/etc/pki/tls/certs",           // Fedora/RHEL
"/etc/openssl/certs",           // NetBSD
"/var/ssl/certs",               // AIX
```

Comment: Are intermediate certs store in the same folder as Root CA certs ?

Answer (score 23):

This will vary from distribution to distribution. For example, on Amazon Linux instances (based on RHEL 5.x and parts of RHEL6, and compatible with CentOS), the certificates are stored in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` and the keys are stored in `/etc/pki/tls/private`. The CA certificates have their own directory, `/etc/pki/CA/certs` and `/etc/pki/CA/private`. For any given distribution, especially on hosted servers, I recommend to follow the already-available directory (and permissions) structure, if one is available.

Comment: Same for CentOS7 as well, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu uses `/etc/ssl/certs`. It also has the command `update-ca-certificates` which will install certificates from `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.

So installing your custom certificates in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and running `update-ca-certificates` seems to be recommended.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/latest/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html

Comment: /etc/ssl/certs is for root certs. That’s not the place to store a server certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers so far, thanks, all!  But since 2009, free SSL cert systems like LetsEncrypt have become the standard, and the modern config is a tad more complicated.

***LetsEncrypt** has three directories, for archiving, active, and renewal for SSL-enabled domains, check them here:*

```
/etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com
/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf
```

***Apache2** has two directories, for enabled and available SSL-enabled domains, check them here:*

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com-le-ssl.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com-le-ssl.conf
```

***LetsEncrypt Archives** eventually get moved to another directory, check it here:*

```
/var/lib/letsencrypt/backups/[TIMESTAMP]/example.com-le-ssl.conf_0
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for a certificate used by your Tomcat instance

1. Open the server.xml file
2. Search for SSL/TLS connector
3. See `keystoreFile` attribute that contains the path to keystore file.

It looks like

```
<Connector
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    port="8443" maxThreads="200"
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```