# Where/how to install intermediate certificates on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7, certificate

Directions for installing CA's are straight forward:

- Copy cert with `.crt` extension to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors`
- then run the command `update-ca-trust extract`

However, I haven't been able to find any instructions on how to install intermediate certs. Is it the same procedure as the CA certs?

Comment: Intermediate certs are usually sent by the server, rather than installed on clients.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I'll accept your comment as answer if you could post that in the answers section.

Comment: Possible duplicate : I think you should find the answer on [this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 1):

Intermediate certs are usually sent by the server, rather than installed on clients.

(**NOTE** Just read the comments to the question, so i'm posting @MichaelHamptons comment as initial answer.)

Comment: By `server` you mean, the web server were the Root CAs are installed or you mean the Intermediate Authority server which would be contacted by the web server to download the Intermediate certificate on demand ?

Comment: Can you please post a new question as it seems you"re looking into a different issue, that the original poster meant. My idea, back than was to get this thread going on to some successful outcome, so i re-posted a comment as an answer. (However, this hasn"t been accepted since)